# Explanation of lines of code about GoogleMaps

Tags: android, google-maps

I know what this line means that retrieves the last known locations, but only because it is written ( .getLastLocation ).
Rather, I would like to know this from the prospective code, which is an object here, why there is parentheses and an equal sign, why are the two words at the beginning and so on. 
I'm new here and I'm learning from the general to the particular, most of the answers is in google, but just that I can not decipher.

```
Location my_new_glocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(ApiClient);
```

Comment: This code has nothing to do with Google Maps. Your questions have nothing to do with Android. Your questions are about Java syntax, and those questions will be answered by any book on Java programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Location` is called the "class", and `my_new_glocation` is object which is an "instance" of that class. You should read up on "object oriented programming" because your question is very basic, but the idea is this...

A class describes the general category of objects, and the object (or instance) is one specific example of an object that would be categorized in that class. For example, "Apple" describes a general category of things. When you go to the supermarket, you probably see hundreds of specific apple objects (or instances) that you can hold in your hand and buy. In this case, Location describes the class of objects, and my_new_glocation describes the specific instance.

Comment: but this program does not have the declared class "Location"

Answer (score 0):

That line is saying "Let a variable of type `Location` that I want to call `my_new_glocation` be whatever `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation` method gives me when I give it `ApiClient`."

But you really should start reading a bit more somewhere else. Learning all things that are this basic by asking them one by one on StackOverflow should not be your preferred method, I think.